# Why is a file read by byte not printing after a full file read

Tags: python, file

Beginner question ;)

Why is the following code not printing the 4 bytes of the file after I have printed the whole file with the above variable?
When I remove the 2 lines with the variable print it prints the 4 bytes perfectly.

```
myFile = open("file.txt")

var= myFile.read()
print(var)

print(myFile.read(4))

myFile.close()
```

Comment: It's because you're at the end of the file after `myfile.read()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myFile.read()` leaves the file pointer at the end of the file; it does not reset automatically at the beginning of the file. You need to do that yourself.

```
with open("file.txt") as myFile:
    var = myFile.read()
    print(var)
    myFile.seek(0)
    print(myFile.read(4))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand!